# Using variables in primary Form from secondary From

Tags: c#, winforms

I am having issues transfering data points from one form to another. I have made sure that the button inside of `addTagsForm` has a public modifier. 
I've looked at multiple solutions of using data values from one form to another and I must be missing something from them.

Here is what I have in `Form1`:

```
//Inside Form1
XMLDocGen.PLCData PLC = new XMLDocGen.PLCData();
List<XMLDocGen.TagData> tags = new List<XMLDocGen.TagData>();
AddTagsForm addTagsForm = new AddTagsForm();
addMoreTagsSelected = addTagsForm.addMoreTagsEnabled;

if(addMoreTagsSelected)
{
   for(int i= 0; i < 8; i++)
   tags.Add(new XMLDocGen.TagData(addTagsForm.addTags[i], addTagsForm.addDataTypes[i], addTagsForm.addElemSizes[i], addTagsForm.addElemCounts[i]));                    
}
```

Here is what is inside of addTagsForm

```
public void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    addMoreTagsEnabled = true;
    var tagNames = new List<TextBox>() { tagNameBoxAMT1, tagNameBoxAMT2, tagNameBoxAMT3, tagNameBoxAMT4, tagNameBoxAMT5, tagNameBoxAMT6, tagNameBoxAMT7, tagNameBoxAMT8 };
    var dataTypes = new List<ComboBox>() { dataTypeBoxAMT1, dataTypeBoxAMT2, dataTypeBoxAMT3, dataTypeBoxAMT4, dataTypeBoxAMT5, dataTypeBoxAMT6, dataTypeBoxAMT7, dataTypeBoxAMT1 };
    var elemSizes = new List<TextBox>() { elemSizeBoxAMT1, elemSizeBoxAMT2, elemSizeBoxAMT3, elemSizeBoxAMT4, elemSizeBoxAMT5, elemSizeBoxAMT6, elemSizeBoxAMT7, elemSizeBoxAMT8 };
    var elemCounts = new List<TextBox>() { elemCountBoxAMT1, elemCountBoxAMT2, elemCountBoxAMT3, elemCountBoxAMT4, elemCountBoxAMT5, elemCountBoxAMT6, elemCountBoxAMT7, elemCountBoxAMT8 };

    for (int i = 0; i < 8; i++)
    {
        addTags.Add(tagNames[i].Text);
        addDataTypes.Add(dataTypes[i].Text);
        addElemSizes.Add(elemSizes[i].Text);
        addElemCounts.Add(elemCounts[i].Text);
    }
    this.Hide();

}
```

I have checked to make sure each list is populated correctly and they are. As well as the Lists being public. The problem is trying to grab these values from Form1. There has to be something simple that I'm missing! Thanks for the help!

Comment: so you're opening your second form from your Form1?

Comment: Can you include the error message, or undesired behavior you're currently getting?

Comment: I don´t understand your question. Which values are used from `Form1` instead of from `addTagsForm`?

Comment: Yes I am. And the `addTagsForm` closes when I hit button1 in the `addTagsForm`

Comment: I am trying to grab the 4 Lists from `addTagsForm` and use them in `Form1`. I am not getting any errors. The Lists in `Form1` are null.

Comment: @NateM24 asking just to get clear idea about your problem- i'm assuming that when you click a button in your Form1 to open your second form that time you want to pass your collection to the second form right?

Comment: Reverse. The `addTagsForm` is 4 sets of 8 TextBoxes/ComboBoxes that the user fills in to use in Form1.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With the reference of your comment i've generated an idea for you. By writing a simple `public` `Action` in your Second form `Form2` you can achieve your goal. Below i'm showing an example:

Declare a `public` `Action` in your `Form2` global scope with your desired collection type, like this way:

```
public Action<List<TextBox>, List<ComboBox>> actGetCollection;
```

Keep a method with some of your desired collection type parameter in your `Form1` like this way:

```
private void GetCollectionItems(List<TextBox> addTags, List<ComboBox> addDataTypes)
{
    //you will get your list items here and do whatever you want with these
}
```

In your `Form1` from where your second form will open bind your `GetCollectionItems()` method with your `Action` in `Form2` (assuming you do this in a button's click event) like this way:

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    //create an instance of your Form2 Form
    Form2 obj = new Form2();
    //bind your function with the action
    obj.actGetCollection = GetCollectionItems;
    //then call your Form2's ShowDialog() method to show the form
    obj.ShowDialog();
    //now your Form2 is opended
}
```

Now in your `Form2`'s button_click event do this:

```
public void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    addMoreTagsEnabled = true;
    var tagNames = new List<TextBox>() { tagNameBoxAMT1, tagNameBoxAMT2, tagNameBoxAMT3, tagNameBoxAMT4, tagNameBoxAMT5, tagNameBoxAMT6, tagNameBoxAMT7, tagNameBoxAMT8 };
    var dataTypes = new List<ComboBox>() { dataTypeBoxAMT1, dataTypeBoxAMT2, dataTypeBoxAMT3, dataTypeBoxAMT4, dataTypeBoxAMT5, dataTypeBoxAMT6, dataTypeBoxAMT7, dataTypeBoxAMT1 };
    var elemSizes = new List<TextBox>() { elemSizeBoxAMT1, elemSizeBoxAMT2, elemSizeBoxAMT3, elemSizeBoxAMT4, elemSizeBoxAMT5, elemSizeBoxAMT6, elemSizeBoxAMT7, elemSizeBoxAMT8 };
    var elemCounts = new List<TextBox>() { elemCountBoxAMT1, elemCountBoxAMT2, elemCountBoxAMT3, elemCountBoxAMT4, elemCountBoxAMT5, elemCountBoxAMT6, elemCountBoxAMT7, elemCountBoxAMT8 };

    for (int i = 0; i < 8; i++)
    {
        addTags.Add(tagNames[i].Text);
        addDataTypes.Add(dataTypes[i].Text);
        addElemSizes.Add(elemSizes[i].Text);
        addElemCounts.Add(elemCounts[i].Text);
    }
    //call the action
    if(actGetCollection != null)
    actGetCollection(addTags, addDataTypes);
    this.Hide();
}
```

When your `Form2` wil disappear your code will get back to your `Form1`'s event from where you're called your `Form2`. Now in your `GetCollectionItems()` you've the collection items that you're wanted.

Comment: Since I am using the textboxes and comboboxes and converting information to strings inside of `button1` to send to Form1, I should change the `Action` and `GetCollectionItems` Lists to strings instead of TextBox/ComboBox, right?

Comment: if you converting them into `string` then of course you can do that.

Comment: My bad, I didn't show the declaration of the Lists in the first place. Thanks again!

Answer (score 1):

You can set stuff in your second form from your first:

```
class Form1
{
...
public void OnButtonPress()
{
    var anotherForm = new Form2();
    anotherForm.AList = mylist;
    anotherForm.BList = myBList;
    anotherForm.ShowDialog();
}
}
```

Alternatively, you could create a class that encapsulates everything you want to pass between the two and so only pass on thing. If it's mandatory I would put it in `Form2`'s constructor:

```
public Form2(MyImportantStuff stuff)
```

Comment: i think the OP was asking the reverse that you've showed.

Comment: Well if he does what I've showed that will work both ways as each object is a reference.